# JQUERY-PHP raffle scroller stop on winning image

Tags: php, jquery, html

currently i have this small Unorganized html list setup

```
<ul>

        <?php 
        $i=0;
        foreach($players as $player){
            $i++;
            if($winner){
                $winnumber = $i;
                echo "<li><span><img src='".$player['avatarfull']."' width='100px' height='100px' /></span></li>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<li><span><img src='".$player['avatarfull']."' width='100px' height='100px' /></span></li>";
            }

        }
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Now the php code gets some images from the database now what i would like to do is make a horizontal scroller that goes from left to right and stops after a certain time and then stops on the winners image the intention is to make a sortoff raffle script so when a person has won it scrolls trough all players and after a selected amount of time stops at the image of the person who won

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, here is how I'd do this:

1. Generate a winner randomly on the PHP side of things.  That keeps things at least a little more in control as for "who" and "how" the winner is determined.
2. I'd create a routine that loops through all the images, animating each one visible.
3. I'd slow the animation down in increments (every 1 sec slow it down by half) after every x amount of images that are shown (so, say after every 2-3 images, slow the animation(s) down by half).
4. Once the animation speed reached a specific threshold (maybe its 1 image/sec) or after i'd looped x amount of times (say 100?), I'd force the very next image to be the winner, allow it to be displayed/rendered visible, and then stop the animation completely..

The rest is just a simple matter of how elegant you want to go with this, how much animation, etc.

Comment: Im quite a JS noob so im kinda looking for an example of some sort where can i build on

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html is a pretty good place to start in that case.  Scroll down to the "Choose Speed and Timeout Values" and "Chose Other Options" sections as they kinda show what you'll want to do for a basic rotator-wheel-style flip.  once you figure that out, customizing it (or even writing your own) should be pretty straight forward bro.